# Prevent floating divs from wrapping wrong

Tags: html, css, css-float

These inner divs are all the same width but the height is variable. The outer div is fluid so we never know how many will fit on each row. I want to prevent the unwanted line wraps as shown in this gloriously artistic example:

[image]

Any way to do this in CSS without Javascript? Here is what I have now:

```
.outer_div {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}
.inner_div {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't clear -- the outer div is fluid so we never know how many will fit on each row. Also the site's not using jQuery so I'd rather avoid that, that's why I asked if it can be done without JavaScript.

Comment: Is floats a must, I'm thinking this is pretty easy with flex?

Comment: Using flexbox and allowing wrapping should work.

Comment: Then don't use float, use e.g. inline block or flexbox

Comment: Interesting, inline-block works, the only problem is that each row is bottom-aligned rather than top-aligned... any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use CSS flexbox on the parent container and allow its content to wrap, i.e. setting `flex-wrap: wrap`, you should be able to achieve the layout you want.

Here is a proof-of-concept example, using ES6 to simply generate random heights for individual boxes for demonstration purposes.

```js
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.inner_div'));

elements.forEach(element => {
  element.style.height = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 50}px`;
});
```

```css
.outer_div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inner_div {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div">
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, the boxes are all fixed-width at 200px though, it's not always going to be 4 that fit on a line.

Comment: @CaymanCarver The width doesn't matter at all in this case: I just picked 25% as a proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, thanks all for your help! The only change needed was to use inline-block instead of float and vertical-align:top on the inner divs like this:

```
.inner_div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
}
```